# rails migration give me incorrect version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, migration, version

I have a weird problem with rails migration, when I do a migration script by typing this command :

```
  rails generate migration my_migration
```

the number of the migration will be an increment of the last migration number, that's annoying because when I started the project the version numbers were correct, as you can see :

```
20140219150827_populate_vehicles_and_goods.rb
20140219154707_create_transport_order_steps.rb
20140951194425_create_countries.rb
20140951194426_import_countries_and_cities.rb
```

I saw on the web that this numbering was an old way to proceed for rails, but I didn't found any way to fix it.

I'm using Rails  3.2.8 and Ruby 1.9.3 and I have tried to set config.active_record.timestamped_migrations to true without any result.

Thanks for your help.

Flo.

Answer (score 0):

Set `config.active_record.timestamped_migrations` to true in application.rb

```
config.active_record.timestamped_migrations = true
```

It should default to true so you might want to check and see if it's set to false either in application.rb or development.rb

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I tried this way to solve, but this is not doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - it was due to a single migration with a bad version timestamp. ActiveRecord seemed to realize it wasn't a valid timestamp and increment from that last version number rather than generate a fresh UTC timestamp.

What fixed the issue for me was renaming the migration with a bad version number to something that represented a reasonable UTC timestamp, and then ActiveRecord seemed to be happy!

When you do that, remember you need to both rename the file AND update the row in the `schema_migrations` table